# Game loop for card game, winner starts, 1 user controlled player

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to program a card game where there is one user-controlled player, playing against 3 a.i opponents. It is a game of Euchre, you can find a similar example here:

https://cardgames.io/euchre/

In this card game, the player that wins the round, starts the next round. The game automatically continues

I am having trouble trying to find a way to handle the user event. The click event needs to action the user-controlled player playing a card, and then the other players in clockwise order.

The problem is that if the user-controlled player does not win the hand, the game must continue playing until the user-controlled player needs to play again, at which point they will be required to fire another click event.

What would be the best way to solve this problem? I have a JSFiddle which I think does what I want, but it's really not ideal:

https://jsfiddle.net/GerardSimpson/m736364e/18/

```
var player1 = {};
player1.hasPlayed = false;
var roundStarter = 0;
var i = 0;
var currentTurn = (i + roundStarter) % 4;
while(player1.hasPlayed === false) {
    console.log("player[",currentTurn,"]", "plays a card");
  i++;
  currentTurn = (i + roundStarter) % 4;
  if(i === 4) {
    roundStarter = 2;
    console.log("Round Over, player "+ roundStarter +" wins");
    i = 0;
    currentTurn = (i + roundStarter) % 4;
  }
  if(currentTurn === 0) {
    console.log("player[ 0 ]s turn, exit loop and wait for new click event");
    player1.hasPlayed = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my problem, the trick was to put the turn functionality into a function that modifies variables in the parent scope that keep a record of the game turn. I think I may need to add closures to this if I don't want to polute the global scope. I will update later, here is my code and fiddle:

```
var player1 = {};
player1.hasPlayed = false;
var roundStarter = 0;
var i = 0;
var currentTurn = (i + roundStarter) % 4;

$('.click-me').on('click', function(){
  while(1) {
    console.log("player[",currentTurn,"]", "plays a card");
    i++;
    currentTurn = (i + roundStarter) % 4;
    if(i === 4) {
      roundStarter = 3;
      console.log("Round Over, player "+ roundStarter +" wins");
      i = 0;
      currentTurn = (i + roundStarter) % 4;
    }
    if(currentTurn === 0) {
      console.log("player[ 0 ]s turn, exit loop and wait for new click event");
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GerardSimpson/m736364e/23/